# How to calculate warehouse cost with AVCO Perpetual method

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

If you have no idea about **AVCO Perpetual method** just read [this article](http://accountingexplained.com/financial/inventories/avco-method) or [this one](http://pakaccountants.com/courses/inventory/average-cost-avco-method/) before going through the question:

To make it more clear I put the data I have in my Transaction table:

[image]

**Quantity column** contains the amount of goods that have been purchased or sold (negative numbers indicate sale invoices)

I need to write a query in SQL Server which returns a record set like this:

[image]

**Cost column** contains the cost of product at the time of transaction which is calculated according to AVCO Perpetual method

Here is the query that you will need to generate table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transactions]
    (
      [Id] [INT] NOT NULL ,
      [Date] [DATE] NOT NULL ,
      [Coefficient] [INT] NOT NULL ,
      [Quantity] [INT] NOT NULL ,
      [Price] [INT] NOT NULL ,
      [Cost] [REAL] NOT NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_Transactions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [Id] ASC )
        WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]
    )
ON  [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT  [dbo].[Transactions]
        ( [Id], [Date], [Coefficient], [Quantity], [Price], [Cost] )
VALUES  ( 1, '2017-01-01', 1, 10, 100, 100 ),
        ( 2, '2017-01-02', 1, 20, 120, 113.33 ),
        ( 3, '2017-01-03', -1, 5, 200, 113.33 ),
        ( 4, '2017-01-04', 1, 10, 150, 123.8 ),
        ( 5, '2017-01-05', -1, 3, 200, 123.8 ),
        ( 6, '2017-01-06', -1, 10, 200, 123.8 ),
        ( 7, '2017-01-07', 1, 10, 180, 141.36 ),
        ( 8, '2017-01-07', -1, 5, 220, 141.36 )
```

**UPDATE**

Just to have a brief view of how I calculated the cost field:

```
((PreviousCost*PreviousStock)+(CurrentPrice*CurrentQuantity))/CurrentStock
```

Comment: If Goods sold how to Calculate Cost. I reached the answer without sales invoice records means Purchase records done. @Saeed Hamed.

Comment: @ShyamVemula I have to consider sold items because the  affects on the stock. I made an update and explained briefly how to calculate cost.

Comment: I hope that the below answer max. reached...

Answer (score 1):

The following Query will fulfill your need.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
 Date1      DATE,
 AvgCost        decimal(18,4)
 )

 DECLARE @QTY       FLOAT,
         @QTY1      FLOAT,
         @Price     FLOAT,
         @Date      DateTime,
         @Cost      FLOAT, 
         @Cost1     FLOAT,
         @RoundCost FLOAT


SELECT @Cost = 0, @QTY = 0, @RoundCost=0
DECLARE Cur_ CURSOR FOR
 SELECT [Date], [Coefficient]*[Quantity], [Price],  ([Quantity] * [Price])  
FROM [dbo].[Transactions]
ORDER BY [Date] ASC, [Coefficient] DESC

OPEN Cur_
FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_ INTO @Date, @QTY, @Price, @Cost
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF(@QTY > 0)
    BEGIN
    SELECT @Cost = @Cost + @RoundCost
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    SELECT @Cost = (@Cost1 * (@QTY+@QTY1))
    END

    SELECT @QTY = @QTY + ISNULL(SUM([Coefficient]*[Quantity]),0)  FROM [dbo].[Transactions]
    WHERE  [Date] < @Date

    --SELECT  @Date, @QTY, @Price,  @Cost,  @Cost / @QTY
    INSERT INTO #Temp
    SELECT  @Date, @Cost / @QTY
    SET @Cost1 = @Cost / @QTY
    SET @QTY1 =  @QTY
    SET @RoundCost = @Cost
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_ INTO @Date, @QTY, @Price, @Cost
END 

CLOSE Cur_
DEALLOCATE Cur_

SELECT * FROM #Temp T
DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Output:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
Date1      AvgCost
---------- ---------------------------------------
2017-01-01 100.0000
2017-01-02 113.3333
2017-01-03 113.3333
2017-01-04 123.8095
2017-01-05 123.8095
2017-01-06 123.8095
2017-01-07 141.3690
2017-01-07 224.5273

(8 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this approach is too slow and I need a query which can be used as a view object. I've come up with recursive table using CTE but that is rather slow as well.